# Apex Tabular form - Add Row button is not adding new row

Tags: oracle-apex

This is for Apex 4.2. After creating a tabular form using the wizard, the Add Row button doesn't add a new row. The Delete & Submit buttons are working fine. Please suggest what could be the issue? Something to do with javascript?

Comment: By default, if you don't modify anything, it works. So - did you modify the page? Enable debug mode, run the page, push the "Add row" button, check debug info. What does it say?

Comment: I haven't modified anything after creating the page. On enabling debug, observed that it has processed it, but the new row added is not visible on the screen.

Comment: That's strange ... I don't have 4.2 any more so I can't test it. Which browser do you use? Do you have any other installed and try to do the same there?

Comment: Tried multiple browsers, same result. However, I created a fresh App with one page alone & then tried tabular form for the same table & it worked. So suspecting some process/script in the other app to be the culprit.

Comment: Maybe; I can't tell. What you could do is to log off, close browser, run it once again and create a brand new tabular form. If it still doesn't work, then you might be right. But - what then???